# How to create a 32-bit integer from eight (8) 4-bit integers?

Tags: javascript, twos-complement, base-conversion

Let's say I have a max 32-bit integer -

```js
const a =
  ((2 ** 32) - 1)
  
const b =
  parseInt("11111111111111111111111111111111", 2) // 32 bits, each is a one!
  
console.log(a === b) // true

console.log(a.toString(2))
// 11111111111111111111111111111111  (32 ones)

console.log(b.toString(2))
// 11111111111111111111111111111111  (32 ones)
```

So far so good. But now let's say I want to make a 32-bit number using eight (8) 4-bit numbers. The idea is simple: shift (`<<`) each 4-bit sequence into position and add (`+`) them together -

```js
const make = ([ bit, ...more ], e = 0) =>
  bit === undefined
    ? 0
    : (bit << e) + make (more, e + 4)

const print = n =>
  console.log(n.toString(2))

// 4 bits
print(make([ 15 ])) // 1111

// 8 bits
print(make([ 15, 15 ])) // 11111111

// 12 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15 ])) // 111111111111

// 16 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // 1111111111111111

// 20 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // 11111111111111111111

// 24 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // 111111111111111111111111

// 28 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // 1111111111111111111111111111

// almost there ... now 32 bits
print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // -1 :(
```

I'm getting `-1` but the **expected** result is 32-bits of all ones, or `11111111111111111111111111111111`.

Worse, if I start with the expected outcome and work my way backwards, I get the expected result -

```js
const c =
 `11111111111111111111111111111111`

const d = 
  parseInt(c, 2)
  
console.log(d) // 4294967295

console.log(d.toString(2) === c) // true
```

I tried debugging my make function to ensure there wasn't an obvious problem -

```js
const make = ([ bit, ...more ], e = 0) =>
  bit === undefined
    ? `0`
    : `(${bit} << ${e}) + ` + make (more, e + 4)

console.log(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) 
// (15 << 0) + (15 << 4) + (15 << 8) + (15 << 12) + (15 << 16) + (15 << 20) + (15 << 24) + (15 << 28) + 0
```

The formula looks like it checks out. I thought maybe it was something to do with `+` and switched to bitwise or (`|`) which should effectively do the same thing here -

```js
const a =
  parseInt("1111",2)
  
const b =
  (a << 0) | (a << 4)
  
console.log(b.toString(2)) // 11111111

const c =
  b | (a << 8)
  
console.log(c.toString(2)) // 111111111111
```

However, I get the same bug with my `make` function when attempting to combine all eight (8) numbers -

```js
const make = ([ bit, ...more ], e = 0) =>
  bit === undefined
    ? 0
    : (bit << e) | make (more, e + 4)

const print = n =>
  console.log(n.toString(2))


print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // 1111111111111111111111111111 (28 bits)

print(make([ 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 ])) // -1 :(
```

What gives?

The goal is to convert eight (8) 4-bit integers into a single 32-bit integer using JavaScript - this is just my attempt. I'm curious where my function is breaking, but I'm open to alternative solutions.

I'd like to avoid converting each 4-bit integer to a binary string, mashing the binary strings together, then parsing the binary string into a single int. A numeric solution is preferred.

Comment: It looks like [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) says _"The numbers `-2147483648` and `2147483647` are the minimum and the maximum integers representable through a 32-bit signed number."_ Indeed `(15 << 28)` lies beyond this range, however JavaScript's [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) supports up to 53 bits. Is there a safe and reliable way to use bitwise operators on larger-than-32-bit numbers?

Comment: Is the signedness really unacceptable? They're the same bits after all, just slightly a different interpretation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bitwise operators will result in a *signed* 32 bit number, meaning that if the bit at position 31 (counting from the least significant bit at the right, which is bit 0) is 1, the number will be negative.

To avoid this from happening, use other operators than `<<` or `|`, which both result in a signed 32-bit number. For instance:

```
(bit * 2**e) + make (more, e + 4)
```

#### Forcing *unsigned* 32-bit

Bit shifting operators are designed to force the result into the signed 32-bit range, at least that is claimed on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Signed_32-bit_integers) (at the time of writing):

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers

This is in fact not entirely true. The `>>>` operator is an exception to this. [EcmaScript 2015, section 12.5.8.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-unsigned-right-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) states that the operands are mapped to *unsigned* 32 bit before shifting in the 0 bits. So even if you would shift *zero* bits, you'd see that effect.

You would only have to apply it once to the final value, like for instance in your `print` function:

```
console.log((n>>>0).toString(2))
```

#### BigInt solution

If you need even more than 32 bits, and your JavaScript engine supports [BigInt](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) like [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) already do, then use BigInts for the operands involved in the bitwise operators -- these will then *not* use the 32-bit signed number wrapping (notice the `n` suffixes):

```js
const make = ([ bit, ...more ], e = 0n) =>
  bit === undefined
    ? 0n
    : (bit << e) + make (more, e + 4n)

const print = n =>
  console.log(n.toString(2))

// Test
for (let i=1; i<20; i++) {
    print(make(Array(i).fill(15n))) // longer and longer array...
}
```

NB: If you get an error running the above, try again with Chrome...

Comment: `bit` is a _bit_ of a misnomer here. Can you actually multiply the 4-bits directly by the exponent there? Typically the base conversion is done using `bit0 * 2**0` + `bit1 * 2**1` + `bit2 * 2**2` + `bit3 * 2**3`, etc. I'm thinking I would have to break the 4-bit segments into individual bits and multiply each one by the increasing exponents.

Comment: No point in guessing, I tried it an it works just fine. Thanks @trincot. I learned a useful shortcut in base conversion today!

Comment: I never felt a "shortcoming" in JavaScript's bitwise operators before today. Is it even reasonable to expect a new set of bitwise operators that works in the 64-bit space?

Comment: It is not really a shortcoming, but intended. I have added a new section to my answer which may interest you.

Comment: that's great. I didn't know BigInt support was already here. The new section makes perfect sense.